# PHP Recordset available?

Tags: php, resultset, recordset

working both with Java and Visual Basic, I see that I can **completely** manage databases with ResultSet (Java) or RecordSet (V.B.). 
I mean, if I read a table from a db with a SELECT query, I can update it without make a new UPDATE or INSERT INTO query. 
Is it possible to do it with PHP?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should clarify how you define RecordSet or what parts of their concrete implementation in Java or VB you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, PHP core doesn't have won't have want you want, but many frameworks built on PHP will, such as http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html or http://www.doctrine-project.org/.

Comment: no it still does a insert/update you're just not seeing it directly by using the framework

Comment: AR is not the same as RecordSet and CI's AR is not even a real AR.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I think that I'll continue to use UPDATE/INSERT INTO queries, I do not like external frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge and it seems more logical (even if less simple) for me.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible as far as I know

to be more precis i doubt you can do it with mysql, im sure though can't remeber their names atm but there are other solutions that might fill your needs, but mysql is a nono